# Access 2013 vba ability to grab a parameterized queries current SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Is there a way to get the SQL of the current query if that query has parameters? EX. say SELECT * FROM Orchard WHERE AppleCount=[how many apples]; and the user wrote in 5.  I would want to get SELECT * FROM Orchard WHERE AppleCount=5;  My current method is to ask the user with input boxes for the parameter but I may be told thats not acceptable, don't ask why.

Comment: If you don't use input boxes, how to know 5 should be passed as parameter? Are you using a form?

Comment: yes, what other method could I use to grab the '5'.  it is in a report

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters from other objects (forms/queries/reports) even VBA into a parameterized query. Does user enter data in a report? Will it always be 5? Please clarify your process in the actual question post.

Comment: The user would open the report, and by default it would ask for "How many apples".  They can type in any number they want, I used 5 as an example.  Currently, I have added input boxes to grab the "How many apples" but these queries have their own input box and if its possible, I would like to use those.

Comment: Remove the report's input boxes and users will be prompted with query inputs.

Comment: correct, but how would I grab what they entered into the input?  With my own input boxes I can easily grab what they wrote in.

Comment: Then keep report's input and reference the report's control in the query: `SELECT * FROM Orchard WHERE AppleCount=Reports!SomeReportName![how many apples];`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is to use your own traps for input - either input boxes or a form, then take those results and pass them to a querydef object via parameters `(yourquerydef.parameters("param name") = <user input>`

You get the parameters from the user, and pass them to the query yourself - no more popups will be presented to user